# Read the latest file from azure blob python

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I have multiple files in an Azure blob. I want to read/download only the latest file.
How can I do it via python.

Note: I am using azure ML datastores to connect to the container in which the blob resides.

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform logic based on blob properties, you'll have to interact with your blob container.

Ensure that you've got the `azure-storage-blob` library :

```
conda install azure-storage-blob
```

(or `pip install` if that's your preference)

In the Azure Portal, navigate to your storage account, choose **Access Keys** in the left-hand rail, and copy one of your **Connection String**s. Also, know the name of the blob container holding your blobs.

Connect and do logic:

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

container = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str={your_connection_string}, container_name = {your_container_name})
for blob in container.list_blobs():
    print(f'{blob.name} : {blob.last_modified}')
```